# Publishing the whole new app with old bundle id/package name/app id

Tags: app-store, windows-store-apps, google-play

Imagine that we have bought other application, then transfer it to our accounts in application stores. Seems like it's possible for all 3 major smartphone platforms.

Imagine then that we bought app for great community, not for app features. Could we publish our own app as an update for bought app?

P.S.: we don't consider possible negative reaction from community, only tech and legal possibility. Also we don't consider that at least in Apple App Store publishing absolutely the same app with different bundle id counts like spamming.

Answer (score 0):

For Google Play **techincally** it is possible to transfer a app from one account to another and yes you can publish other app as the update for the existing one as long as your app has the same package name as the existing one.

http://phandroid.com/2012/06/21/getting-acquired-how-to-transfer-ownership-of-your-android-app-or-game/